# How to disable the cancel when a popupwindow shows

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I created a popupwindow to show a menu. I found that if I press the cancel button on keyboard, the popupwindow will dismiss, and *setFocusable()* only disable the buttons like menu, but cancel button still works.
If there exists a method to make popupwindow invalid for popupwindow, or define the action myself when a cancel button is pressed? Thanks.

Well I mean back button when i say cancel button. And Thanks for sachy and other people who reply me.

Comment: You mean how to disable onBackPressed() when popup (menu) is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cancel button do you mean back button? If yes than u can simply override `onKeyDown()`.

```
 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d("back", "back button pressed");
    }
    return true; //to prevent this event from being propagated further.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please explain more to now exactly what you want to achieve. If you just want to disable the button you might try this.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Or you want to override the cancel button? Check this out then: [Back button behavior](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/back-button-behavior.html)

Comment: Bare with me. It's my first answer.

Comment: Please have a look at the formatting buttons on top of the form for your next post. Have a nice stay here!

Comment: Actually I mean back button, I just want to diable it when a popupwindow shows. Thank you for your answer.